Verifying $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}}_{\lambda}f\in\mathcal{H}$ using density (Mathematical Geophysics Proposition 2.3)
I meet a problem when reading Chemin's Mathematical Geophysics. In page 40 Proposition 2.3 he writes:
The map
$$
\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}\begin{cases}
\mathcal{V}'\rightarrow\mathcal{V}'_{\sigma}\\
f\mapsto v\mapsto\langle f,\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}v\rangle
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies
$$
\forall f\in\mathcal{V}'_{\sigma},\ \widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}} f\in\mathcal V_{\sigma}.
$$
where in my opinion the definition of $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}$ should be understood as
$$
\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}:f\mapsto\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f\ \mathrm{s.t.}\ \forall v\in\mathcal{V}_{\sigma},\ \langle\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f,v\rangle=\langle f,\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}v\rangle.
$$
Here $\mathcal{V}'$ is the space of vector fields with $H^{-1}$ components, $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ is the space of divergence-free vector fields in $\mathcal{V}$, $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ is the space of continuous linear forms on $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$, $\mathcal{V}$ is the space of vector fields with $H_0^1$ components.
In proof he writes:
... for any $v\in\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$,
$$
\langle\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f,v\rangle\le\|f\|_{\mathcal{V}'}(1+\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}})\|v\|_{\mathcal{H}}
$$
As $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ we find that $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f$ is in $\mathcal{H}$.
(Here $\mathcal{H}$ is the closure of $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ in $L^2$.)
My problem is that why $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ is dense can lead to $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f\in\mathcal{H}$? I don't know how to use estimate of $\langle\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f,v\rangle$. Since by definition  $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f\in\mathcal{V}'_{\sigma}$, I think $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f\in\mathcal{H}$ means the regularity of $\widetilde{\boldsymbol{P}_{\lambda}}f$ is raised, but I don't understand how to show it using density of $\mathcal{V}_{\sigma}$ :( I'll be glad if you have any opinion.
